# Mapping float type as ID on fluent nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, primary-key

I am new to nhibernate and trying to map a column which has float on sql server schema (it cannot be changed).  Below is my domain:

```
public class Versionhistory {
    [Required]
    public virtual float Versionnumber { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual DateTime Dateapplied { get; set; }
}
```

Below is my mapping:

```
    public class VersionhistoryMap : ClassMap<Versionhistory> {

    public VersionhistoryMap() {
        Table("VersionHistory");
        LazyLoad();
        Id(x => x.Versionnumber).GeneratedBy.Identity().Column("VersionNumber");
        Map(x => x.Dateapplied).Column("DateApplied").Not.Nullable();
    }
}
```

I am getting the error, "Identity type must be integral (int, long, uint, ulong)"

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this column can only use Integer types when Autogenerating Ids but you can try:

```
   Id(x => x.VersionNumber)
       .GeneratedBy.Identity()
       .Column(className + "_Id")
       .CustomType("Float");
```

Comment: sorry i tried that but doesn't works. I think CustomType is for like VARCHAR2, etc

Comment: That's CustomSQLType. CustomType tells NHibernate which type should be used to map the item itself